# Why is strand sort O(n sqrt n) in the average case?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I found [strand sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand_sort) very appealing to sort singly linked lists in constant space, because it is much faster than for example insertion sort.

I see why it is `O(n)` in the best case (the list is already sorted) and `O(n^2)` in the worst case (the list is reversely sorted). But why `O(n sqrt n)` in the average case? If algorithm is not based on bisection and has polynomial best-case and worst-case performance, is the average case just `O(n^m)`, where `m` is arithmetic mean of best-case's and worst-case's exponents (`m = (1 + 2) / 2 = 3/2`, `O(n sqrt n) = O(n^(3/2))`)?

Comment: Watching this question. I am also wondering how it is 'n sqrt (n)'

Comment: No, average-case analysis is usually far more complicated. (The difficult cases might be rare or common, for example.)

Comment: Comb Sort should be able to sort singly linked lists in constant space with O(n log n) time complexity.

Comment: Plain old merge sort uses O(1) space for linked lists (unlike for arrays when O(n) working space is needed).  It's O(n log n) of course.  You can also use quicksort on linked lists, which needs O(log n) stack space and has an O(n^2) worst case, but just O(n log n) best- and average-case complexity.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you for pointing out that mergesort can be implemented using O(1) space for lists.

Comment: Why do you think it is O(n sqrt n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original reference to Strand sort is http://groups.google.com/group/fido7.ru.algorithms/msg/26084cdb04008ab3 ... according to that, it is O(n^2). Strand sort was presented as a component of J sort, which it claims is O(n lg n). That the average complexity is O(n^2) makes sense since, in random data, half the strands will be of length 1, and O((n/2)^2) = O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks for the resource.  That half the strands in an average random input would be length one does not seem true to me.  At least by the Wikipedia definition, streands do not have to be continuous.  Therefore, for a strand to be of length one means that its first element is greater than all later elements not already consumed by a strand, but not so great as to have already become the tail of another strand itself.

Comment: You are right, strands need not be continuous -- I misread the reference. I'll have to rethink the complexity issue, but the reference does state that it's n-squared.

Answer (score 0):

On the Wikipedia page that you linked to, the average case performance is O(n lg n) with a citation to this Stack Overflow page. Which is weird because nowhere on this page does it say that.

Anyway, to further what Ulrich was saying, average-case analysis is complicated because it has to take into account how the data is represented on average, which is not trivial.

**From Wikipedia:**

> Determining what average input means is difficult, and often that average input has properties which make it difficult to characterise mathematically (consider, for instance, algorithms that are designed to operate on strings of text). Similarly, even when a sensible description of a particular "average case" (which will probably only be applicable for some uses of the algorithm) is possible, they tend to result in more difficult to analyse equations.

Comment: For comparison sorts algorithms, "average complexity" means *expected value of the number of comparisons, for uniformly random permutations as input*. This is perfectly well defined, but may be quite difficult to compute. More interesting than the expected value is the law of the number of comparisons.

Comment: Really? I don't think average-case analysis uses random permutations. It is more based up the input which is situational.

Comment: It depends.  For example, in the CLR(S) quicksort's averaged case performance is first discussed by choosing an intuitively "bad" case and showing that it has O(n lg n) performance.  Later a rigorous analysis determines the expected performance under certain assumptions.

Comment: "situational" implies arbitrary, subjective, and computationally intractable. Fortunately that's not what "average" means:

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity: 

"Average-case complexity is a subfield of computational complexity theory that studies the complexity of algorithms on random inputs."